# Do the following random variable exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $(S,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ be probability space.

Is there a random variable $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{F})\to (S,\mathcal{S})$ that satisfies $P(X\in A)=\mu(A)  (\forall A \in \mathcal{S})$

I think there is, but I forgot how I constructed $X$

I'd appreciate any advice, no matter how trivial, even if $S=\mathbb{R}^d$

Comment: If $\Omega = \{0\}$ then $P(X \in A) = 1_{X(0) \in A}$ so that the only measures that have such a representation in this case are dirac measures.

Comment: No, in general there is not. What is true is that if you have a probability space and a measurable function, then that measurable functions creates an "image measure" on its codomain; in the case of random variables that is the distribution.